# How to make sure one feature is included in all trees in random forest

Tags: random-forest, sklearn-pandas

Currently I'm using sklearn to build a random forest classifier, but I want to make sure that one specific feature, which I think is the most important one, will be included in all generated decision trees.

What is the easiest way to do this? Should I implement a customized random forest algorithm by myself or just change the source code of the sklearn package? If so, how can I change it? Thanks!

Comment: can you add your code- attempt and some data? this questions is very general

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a `RandomForestClassifier` object with the `warm_start` attribute set to true. Fit the RF, iterate over its member trees (as listed in the `estimators_` attribute), and delete all that do not contain this presumably very important feature. Repeat the process until you have a RF model with the required number of feature-active member trees ready.